# tizen simulator block iframe content

Tags: javascript, iframe, tizen, tizen-web-app

I'm new to Tizen.My script loads an iframe which loads external scripts in addition.
In the network tab I can see the script requests as cancelled.

I added `sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin"` but with no help.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Add these in **config.xml**

```
<tizen:allow-navigation>*</tizen:allow-navigation>
```

If you only one domain. You can:

```
<tizen:allow-navigation>yourdomain.com</tizen:allow-navigation>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add these in **config.xml**

```
<tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/internet"/>
<access origin="**yourdomain.com**" subdomains="true"></access>
<access origin="*" subdomains="true"></access>
<tizen:content-security-policy>self</tizen:content-security-policy>
```

Use your domain instead of **yourdomain.com**
Also see [this post.](https://developer.tizen.org/forums/web-application-development/problem-loading-external-page)